# HttpClient how to retrieve rejected cookie

Tags: java, httpclient, resteasy

I am using resteasy client 3.0.6 and httpclient 4.5.2 and I got following warnings when performing a GET request:

```
Apr 19, 2018 12:40:18 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Cookie rejected [MY_COOKIE_IDENTITY="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCIgOiAiNzE5OTk3ZGQtNjVhZi00OTMwLTgwMjYtYWU3ZjIxZDYyYWI3In0.eyJqdGkiOiIyZjdh...", version:1, domain:psp208.fx.lan, path:/auth/210, expiry:null] Illegal 'path' attribute "/auth/210". Path of origin: "/auth/001"
Apr 19, 2018 12:40:18 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Cookie rejected [MY_COOKIE_SESSION="epos210/770a1a6f-1901-4985-8330-5aab4f9febe8/5f45c340-dfb6-466a-8f96-9d5a3cc51643", version:0, domain:psp208.fx.lan, path:/auth/210, expiry:Thu Apr 19 22:40:18 CEST 2018] Illegal 'path' attribute "/auth/210". Path of origin: "/auth/001"
```

but even if they are defined with an illegal path, I want to retrieve them programatically. Currently I am trying to use the following snippet:

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(20).httpEngine(apacheHttpClient4Engine).build();
client.register(new ClientRequestFilter(){

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext arg0) throws IOException {
        cookies.putAll(arg0.getCookies());
    }

});
```

but the filter is never invoked.

After looking HttpClient documentation I tried creating my own CookieSpecProvider:

```
Registry<CookieSpecProvider> r = RegistryBuilder.<CookieSpecProvider>create()
    .register("easy", new CookieSpecProvider(){

        @Override
        public CookieSpec create(HttpContext arg0) {
            return new BrowserCompatSpec(){

                @Override
                public void validate(org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie cookie, CookieOrigin origin)
                        throws MalformedCookieException {

                    // empty implementation
                }


            };
        }

    })
.build();
```

by using this implementation the ClientRequestFilter is invoked but it is returning an empty map of cookies.

My goal is to retrieve the two cookies I get from the response. How can I do it ?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding a cookie store

```
    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    CloseableHttpClient closableclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig)      
            .setDefaultCookieSpecRegistry(registry)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();
```

In this way I can retrieve cookies without ClientRequestFilter.